# Replicating Django User Passwords

Tags: django, sqlite

I am currently trying to seperate my current Django sqlite3 database into 2 databases. This requires replicating some user accounts from the old database to the new one. Is it possible to replicate/copy a User object since the raw password is not stored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily replicate. Django authenticates `Users` using their password hash. Just make sure you have the same password hashers enabled in your `settings.py`

i.e.

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
)
```